# java.util.Vector<E> Roadblock

Tags: java, binding, vector, comet

Referring to: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#addElement(E)

I have an assignment for my OOP class where I have to write classes for a Asteroids-like java game. I have to use vectors to represent the x and y positions as well as the x and y velocities of the shots and the comets. So, when they are initialized, they look like this: "public Vector shots;" and "public Vector comets;". I'm having issues getting shots.size() to not equal zero when the for loop inside updateShots() is called, thus it's not getting to the part where the shot actually fires. Every time I try and add elements to the vector, it tells me that the element must be of type "Shot" and that it can't convert my double to that type. I've been searching online for hours and hours and can't find anything that doesn't use Double, String, Integer, or Object as the binding for the Vector class. I assume it has something to do with my Shot.class and something that needs to be added to that class. I'm not sure what code of mine I could post on here to help describe what issue I'm having.

This is how the files are setup: CometsMain.java is the main java file; SpaceObjects is the overall class with 3 subclasses; Comet, Ship, and Shot are the 3 subclasses of SpaceObject, each extending SpaceObject; then Comet has 3 subclasses that aren't important at this time.

The initialization I specified in the beginning it located in CometsMain.java. The Ship class has a method "Shot fire()", returning a new shot. The Shot class handles the "move()" method, actually controlling the bullets movement. I currently have all vector related code for the shot inside move(), inside the actual Shot class, but am not sure if it all needs to be in there or in the "Shot fire()" method inside Ship.class.

Let me know what code you would like me to post or what other information is needed.

Comment: tl;dr - please post some code demonstrating the problem you are having.

Comment: Your question is too long and unclear. If the problem is adding things to the vector then we need to see the error, the code that produces the error and the definitions of the objects involved in the error.

Comment: I had the vector addition in the complete wrong place so the error I was getting was too vague to know what small part of code it was inside. I figured it out though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using Java's Vector class for this. Your assignment is to use vectors in the mathematical sense, not in the sense of the Java collections framework (to which java.util.Vector belongs). You can define your own vector class (preferable), or just use an array of two ints as your vectors. You can even name your class Vector; the compiler will know which one to use provided you don't import java.util.Vector (or java.util.*). If you do need to import java.util.Vector, then you'll just have to use the fully qualified class name instead of the bare name Vector.

Comment: My teacher told us to specifically use the java.util.Vector class. I am supposed to use this Vector class and I figured it out. I have the code that was trying to add to the vector in the wrong place. I had it in a subclass and not the main java file. Also, I figured out how to call my class. I used "shots.add(ship.fire());" in the main java and then the "Shot fire();" method inside the Ship class returns a "new Shot(....)" thus adding the shot to the vector. Thanks for your help though, I'm sorry if the explanation in my original post was hard to follow i was a little out of it by that time.